# Ruby on Rails, saving boolean value in a cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

**Background information**

I want to have a settings form on my web application, that allows the user to set some basic settings for the experience inside the app. I am making a javascript that takes care of what has to be done depending on the settings people choose.

The thing is... I want my to users have their settings automatically saved when they change anything, in a cookie. I haven't worked out the AJAX needed yet, but I have ran into an early problem.

**My problem**

I can't make a cookie change the "checked'ness" of a checkbox.

I have this form.

*views/rooms/index.html.haml*

```
= form_tag settings_path, method: 'post' do
  = label_tag :my_boolean
  = check_box_tag :my_boolean, cookies[:my_boolean]
  = submit_tag
```

and this controller

*controllers/settings_controller.rb*

```
def index
  cookies[:my_boolean] = params[:my_boolean]
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

It works alright when I use a textfield instead of a checkbox.

**Also**

If you can help me making this more restfull, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `SettingsController'

routes could have
`match "/settings/toggle/:setting" => "settings#toggle", as: :toggle_settings`

this way you can use controller action `toggle` for booleans. and other actions for other settings updates

then you can utilize `"1"` or `"0"` for booleans inside the settings. and later wrap a model around the cookies.